# String comparison in javascript fails

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have a problem when comparing two strings. the problem is that when i compare the equality of `status` variable with `"success"` string literal it returns `False`, However when I check the value of the `success` via `alert` or `console.log` I get `"success"`.

when I use `status.valueOf() == "success"` I get an error which says `Can not call method 'valueOf' of undefined` but when checking

```
// this is a callback function used in jQuery.post(url, data, callback)
this.callback = function(data, status, jqXHR) { 
    alert(status); // shows that status is equal to "success"
    console.log("STATUS: " + status);
console.log("STATUS CONSTRUCTOR: " + status.constructor);
console.log("STATUS TYPE: " + (typeof status));
    if(status.valueOf() === "success") {
        var data = JSON.parse(data);
        if(data.errors) {
            this.success(data.message);
        } else {
            this.failure(data.message, data.errors);
        }
    } else {
        alert("WTF");
    }
};
```

**UPDATE 2:**

This is what i get after logging some attributes of the `status`:

```
>>>console.log("STATUS: " + status);
STATUS: success add_poll.js:34
>>>console.log("STATUS CONSTRUCTOR: " + status.constructor);
STATUS CONSTRUCTOR: function String() { [native code] } add_poll.js:35
>>>console.log("STATUS TYPE: " + (typeof status));
STATUS TYPE: string add_poll.js:36
STATUS: undefined add_poll.js:34
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined add_poll.js:35
(callback add_poll.js:35)
(callback add_poll.js:41)
(fire jquery.js:1037)
```

Comment: `Can not call method 'valueOf' of undefined` means that the object status does not have the function valueOf, better check that...

Comment: console.log(status) see what you get

Comment: Please check what does status carrying from your controller, I think it is carring nothing

Comment: @Suganthan please read my updated question.

Comment: Are you saying the code as shown in the update successfully alerts `"success"` _and_ produces the error about `undefined.valueOf()`?

Comment: @nnnnnn yes that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. The problem is that I defined the callback function as a property of an object `this.callback = function(){...};` I changed it and defined a normal javascript function and it worked. Actually I don't know why? Anyone knows why I can't use an object method as a callback function for `$.post(url, data, callback)`?

Answer (score 2):

> Can not call method 'valueOf' of undefined

The error message says, `valueOf` is called on `undefined`. It means that the `status` is `undefined`. So, you might want to drop the `valueOf` and simply do

```
if (status === "success") {
```

Comment: How status could be undefined when I check it's value which is `success`?

Comment: @user3061142 Can you please show us your problem with a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1):

A better way of checking might be,

```
if(status.toLowerCase() === "success")
```

Comment: is it necessary to use toString() here?

Comment: not necessary as it is sure type is string in this case, edited!

Answer (score 0):

First check what you server code is returning, if it is ok, try this

```
if (status === "success")
```

or you can do this

```
 if (data=== "success")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The method you are using for jQuery ajax is almost deprecated.
2. As already mentioned in comment, there is no need of using `valueOf` method with status

So, this should do

```
$.ajax({

    url: 'url2ajax.php',
    dataType: 'datatype returned by the url ajaxed maybe json',
    data: {//list of key-value pairs to be send },
    success: function( oData ) {
        //call back to perform on a successful ajax.
        //Data returned from ajaxed url available as argument, oData
    },
    error: function( ojQXhr, strStat, strErr ) {
        //callback to perform on a failed ajax request
        //jQuery XHR object, status string and error message available as argument
    }

});
```

Refer to [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for details